# jps equivalent command in AIX

Tags: java, aix, jvm-arguments

I am looking for **jps** equivalent command in AIX platform.

On Linux , using jps command, i get all the JVM options specified:

```
jps -lvm

85243  -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions -XX:-UseParallelGC -verbose -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrs -XX:-UseBiasedLocking
```

Need similar or equivalent command in AIX operating system. I googled for the command but did not find any.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ps -eaf | grep java** to list all java processes.
Also this gives you the complete command-line using which you can see the passed arguments to the JVM.